# Boomi - Merge two JSONs

Tags: json, merge, boomi

I have two inbound JSON data sets that I need to combine/merge in Boomi

**Inbound DataSet1**

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Program": [
        {
            "ProgramId": "A",
            "ProgramName": "ProgramA"
        },
        {
            "ProgramId": "B",
            "ProgramName": "ProgramB"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

**Inbound DataSet2**

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Course": [
        {
            "CourseId": "C1",
            "CourseName": "Course 1"
        },
        {
            "CourseId": "C2",
            "CourseName": "Course 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Want to Combine them to the following:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Program": [
        {
            "ProgramId": "A",
            "ProgramName": "ProgramA"
        },
        {
            "ProgramId": "B",
            "ProgramName": "ProgramB"
        }
    ],
    "Course": [
        {
            "CourseId": "C1",
            "CourseName": "Course 1"
        },
        {
            "CourseId": "C2",
            "CourseName": "Course 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I defined a JSON profile with the final expected output which has Program and Course in it - however, in Data Processing when I am trying to do a Combine JSON, I am unable to choose either elements or keys to merge the documents on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Kris's advise and did the following:

- Added to Cache
- Then combined it in a map for the unique Id
- So now we have individual documents where its combined, but each document is separate, we need to combine them
- In order to do so, I added a message step where i added the following: '{"Data":['{1}']}' where {1} is the current data
- Now each document is inside the array
- Next I used Data process to combine the documents with the common array object

See the final process in the link below. Reach out if you have questions.

[Boomi Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibp7z.png)

Answer (score 0):

The approach necessitates the creation of three data profiles: one for each dataset and one for the combined format.

You load dataset2 into a document cache (make sure you have "Enforce one index entry per document" selected and that you have a document key), then you get the dataset1 into a Map (shape). In this Map, you do a lookup (Add cached data) to dataset2 based on the "Id".
This will get you both profiles combined based on the Id.

The Map needs a target profile, which is where you put your combined format profile and map the fields from datasets 1 and 2 to the final profile.

I hope it helps..